# passing data from detail view to a table view ios 4

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios4

I have two views, the first (view A) is a table view. Every row has a disclosure button, when I click on the button I display the second view (view B) which is a table view too. When i click on a row, I want to pass the data to view A and display it as `detailTextLabel`.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface A : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    NSDictionary *listData;
    NSArray *keys;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *listData;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *keys;
@end


#import "A.h"
@implementation A
@synthesize listData;
@synthesize keys;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [listData release];
    [keys release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Criteres" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    self.listData = dict; 
    [dict release];
    NSArray *array = [[listData allKeys]sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    self.keys = array;
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    self.listData = nil;
    self.keys = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - 
#pragma mark Table View Data Source Methods

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{ 
    return [keys count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:section]; 
    NSArray *nameSection = [listData objectForKey:key]; 
    return [nameSection count];
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:section]; 
    return key;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    NSUInteger section = [indexPath section]; 
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:section]; 
    NSArray *nameSection = [listData objectForKey:key];
    static NSString *SectionsTableIdentifier = @"SectionsTableIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SectionsTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:SectionsTableIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [nameSection objectAtIndex:row]; 
    if (section == 0) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
        if (row == 2)
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"En m2";
        if (row == 1)
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"En €";
    }

    if (section == 1) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
        }
    }   
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - 
#pragma mark Table Delegate Methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSUInteger row = 2; 
    return row;
}

-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return indexPath;
    }

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *ownerCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([ownerCell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Ecole"]) {
        B *prixview = [[B alloc]init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:prixview animated:YES];
        prixview.title = @"prix";
    }
    if ([ownerCell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Crèche"]) {
        B *prixview = [[B alloc]init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:prixview animated:YES];
        prixview.title = @"Prix";
    }
}
@end



#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface B : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    NSArray *typetab;
    NSInteger radioSelectionTypeBien;
    NSString *radioSelectionTypeBienString;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *typetab;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *radioSelectionTypeBienString;
@end


#import "B.h"
@implementation B
@synthesize typetab;
@synthesize radioSelectionTypeBienString;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [self.radioSelectionTypeBienString release];
    [self.typetab release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                 initWithTitle:@"Critères" 
                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                 target:self
                                 action:@selector(backButtonActionTypeBien:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
    [backButton release];
    radioSelectionTypeBien = -1;
    NSArray *type = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Appartement",@"Maison",@"Commerce", nil ];
    self.typetab = type;
    [type release];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

-(IBAction)backButtonActionTypeBien: (id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.navigationController.parentViewController animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    self.radioSelectionTypeBienString = nil;
    self.typetab = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - 
#pragma mark Table View Data Source Methods 

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{ 
    return [self.typetab count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) { cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
                                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.textLabel.text = [typetab objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (indexPath.row == radioSelectionTypeBien){ 
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    radioSelectionTypeBien = indexPath.row;
    radioSelectionTypeBienString = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text;
    [tableView reloadData];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually i write a method in the controller `B` like:

```
-(voi)initVCwithString:(NSString*)_string andSomeObject:(NSObject *)_obj;
```

(so the controller B must have 2 ivar, a string and an object, that you have to set in this method)

then call this in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`: from the controller `A`

```
...
B _vcB=//alloc..init..etc
[_vcB initVCwithString:yourCell.textLabel.text andSomeObject:someObj];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:_vcB animated:YES];
[_vcB release];
```

Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` of `B` set `cell.detailTextLabel.text=yourStringIvar;`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are two possibilities that seems to be suitable. You can write a custom delegate method which pass the value to the A controller, or you can make a notification via notification centre, which can then assign the value to the A controller by catching the notification which will be triggered by picking a  cell in the controller B.